# Validating specific identifier pattern

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have **strings (identifiers)** like the following samples

```
CRMG-1933071636600-001.PUPS.0WZMWZi8-oiiT1TE
```

or

```
PALIM-1971123014100-001.RCRD.J25PL5DG-00KBY4G
```

that might be summarized

```
XXXX-1971123014100-001.ZZZZ.J25PL5DG-00KBY4G
```

**XXXX** may take any of the following values: *CRMG*, *PALIM*, *FEDUC* ...
and
**ZZZZ** my take any of the following values: *MCPR*, *MCSC*, *PUPS*, *RCRD* ...

**I tried the following expression pattern**:

```
[ACVC,ALHAND,ATI,AVC,CRMG,FEDUC,GERO,PALIM,PFP,CRMG,RPGH]-[0-9]{11}-[0-9]{3}\.[AVAN,MCPR,MCSC,PUPO,PUPS,PUSO,PUSS,RCRD,RMBI]\.[a-zA-Z]{8}-[0-9a-zA-Z]{7}
```

and it's not validating the above string examples.

Can someone please tell me how to match those XXXX and ZZZZ strings and how to express the bolded parts correctly?

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a lot of issues here:

- Defining alternation inside a longer pattern is done using a *grouping construct*, `(...|...)` or `(?:...|...)`, so you need to replace all `[a,b,c]` with `(a|b|c)` / `(?:a|b|c)`
- The second part contains 13 digits, not 11 digits
- Also, escape the dots as a dot outside square brackets is a special regex metacharacter.

```js
(ACVC|ALHAND|ATI|AVC|CRMG|FEDUC|GERO|PALIM|PFP|CRMG|RPGH)-[0-9]{13}-[0-9]{3}\.(AVAN|MCPR|MCSC|PUPO|PUPS|PUSO|PUSS|RCRD|RMBI)\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}-[0-9a-zA-Z]{7}
```

Or,  if you are validating standalone strings, add `^` and `$` anchors around the pattern:

```js
^(ACVC|ALHAND|ATI|AVC|CRMG|FEDUC|GERO|PALIM|PFP|CRMG|RPGH)-[0-9]{13}-[0-9]{3}\.(AVAN|MCPR|MCSC|PUPO|PUPS|PUSO|PUSS|RCRD|RMBI)\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}-[0-9a-zA-Z]{7}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qMFWET/1).